# Runnable thread stuck/freezes the ui after continuously loading webview

Tags: android, freeze, ui-thread, webviewrunonuithread

Due to loading webview coninuously using my runnable thread in android , my application freezes after some time.
below is my code:

```
mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
          public void run() {

              System.gc();
              if(i%15==0)
              {
                  clearApplicationData();
                  cookieManager.removeAllCookie();

              }
              browser.clearCache(true);
              browser2.clearCache(true);
              browser3.clearCache(true);
              browser4.clearCache(true);
              browser5.clearCache(true);
              try{
              browser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/go.swf");
              Thread.sleep(100);
              browser2.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/go.swf");
              Thread.sleep(100);
              browser3.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/go.swf");
              Thread.sleep(100);
              browser4.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/go.swf");
              Thread.sleep(100);
              browser5.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/go.swf");
              }
              catch(Exception e)
              {
                  Log.d("TAG ERROr","-----------------------"+e.toString());
              }

          i=i+1;
          mHandler.postDelayed(this, 20000);
          }
       };
       new Thread(mUpdateTimeTask).start();
```

Comment: Post the full code here

Comment: i see  System.gc() =/

Comment: I  am creating a player where i have to run flash content in android webview again and again. But after 30 minutes my application start freezing. System.gc is used to call gc, where others are used to clear webview cache when thread calls again

Comment: The code is completed because it is a thread